# Adding a validation field for sign in using Devise and Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, warden

I'm trying to add another field in the sign in page using Devise and Rails 4.0.  A user needs to provide their username, password and an organization/location code.  A user has_and belongs_to_many locations, and when logged in, this organization code should be saved in sessions.

At this point, I think I got most of it working (please let me know if there is a better way of doing this), but I don't know how to handle what happens if an invalid location code is entered.  Here's what I have so far.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params["user"]["username"])
    org_code = params["user"]["check_org_code"].downcase
    user.locations.each do |location|
      if location.org_code == org_code
        super
        session[:location] = location
      else
        < return a warden.authenticate! fail? >
        super
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially solved this by using throw(:warden) and while this works, is probably not the best solution.  Later I came across a custom devise strategy example by [r00k](https://gist.github.com/r00k/906356) and implemented my own variation.  I've included both solutions below.

**r00k-esque solution**
N.B. there were some bits of code is r00k's solution that didn't work for me.  In case r00k's solution isn't working for you, please note the differences with "fail!" and "valid_password?".

```
# config/initializers/local_override.rb

require 'devise/strategies/authenticatable'

module Devise
  module Strategies
    class LocalOverride < Authenticatable
      def valid?
        true
      end

      def authenticate!
        if params[:user]
          user = User.find_by_username(params["user"]["username"])
          if user.present?
            code = params["user"]["check_org_code"].downcase
            codes = user.locations.pluck(:org_code).map{ |code| code.downcase }
            check_code = code.in?(codes)
            check_password = user.valid_password?(params["user"]["password"])

            if check_code && check_password
              success!(user)
            else
              fail!(:invalid)
            end
          else
            fail!(:invalid)
          end
        else
          fail!(:invalid)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

Warden::Strategies.add(:local_override, Devise::Strategies::LocalOverride)

# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :local_override
end
```

**Initial solution**

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params["user"]["username"])
    org_code = params["user"]["check_org_code"].downcase
    matching = false

    user.locations.each do |location|
      if location.org_code == org_code
        super
        session[:location] = location
        matching = true
        break
      end
    end

    if matching == false
      throw(:warden, :message => :invalid)
    end
  end
end
```